# Get Bootstrap Buttons Value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form with multiple bootstrap buttons. When the user clicks on the button I want to refine results.

The issue I have is trying to get the value of the button**s** clicked in the javascript function that is called to refine the results.

The code for the buttons is below

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary active">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="btnPublic" checked> Public Questions
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="btnPrivate"> Private Questions
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary active">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="btnQuestionsForMe" checked> Questions For Me
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="btnQuestionsIAsked"> Questions I Asked
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I get the value of the two separate buttons via javascript in the same function.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you will only ever be able to have one radio button checked, since all of your radio button names are called "options".  If you want the user to be able to select two of the four radio buttons you will need to change the names of the radio buttons you want to be grouped together.  I have put together a nice [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vG8T/) example for you that does what you are asking.

You will need to attach a change event to each radio button so you know when buttons are checked.  Example:

```
$("#btnQuestionsForMe").change(function(){
   doSomethingWithCheckedRadio()
});
```

Here is the javascript code using jquery to get all of the checked radio buttons:

```
function getCheckedRadios(){
    var checkedIds = [];        
    $("input[type='radio']").each(function(i, obj){
        if($(this).prop("checked")){
             checkedIds.push($(this).attr("id"));   
        }
    });        
    return checkedIds;
}
```

Hope this helps!